# How to add objects to a key within another dynamically created object in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-objects

I'm using Angular to create a list app. For testing purposes I have two pre-created lists each with pre-created names and items. Eventually the user will initially be presented with an empty list to which they can add items. Then they can add a new list for new items. So far I have the ability to add and remove items to and from the existing list, and I can add a new list. But I can't add new items to a newly created list. I get a "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" error for the line `list.items.push(this.item);`. My guess is that when I create a new list, there is no `items` key added to it and that's why it's undefined. I tried creating an `items` key when I create a new list, but I couldn't get it to work. That might not be the problem anyway.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWRQvQ

Here's the markup:

```
<div ng-app="notepadApp">
    <div ng-controller="notepadController as notepadCtrl">
        <header ng-repeat="list in notepadCtrl.lists">
            <div>Delete list</div>
            <h1>{{list.name}}</h1>
        </header>
        <div ng-repeat="list in notepadCtrl.lists" class="shoppingList" ng-controller="ItemController as itemCtrl">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in list.items">

                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked">
                        {{item.name}}
                    </label>
                    <form name="itemForm" ng-submit="itemCtrl.removeItem(list, $index)">
                        <input type="submit" value="remove">
                    </form>

                </li>
            </ul>
            <form name="itemForm" ng-submit="itemCtrl.addItem(list)">
                <input type="text" ng-model="itemCtrl.item.name">
                <input type="submit" value="Add item">
            </form>
        </div>

        <form name="addListForm" ng-submit="notepadCtrl.addList(lists)">
            <input type="text" ng-model="notepadCtrl.list.name">
            <input type="submit" value="Add list">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This script is:

```
(function(){

var app = angular.module('notepadApp', []);

var shoppingLists = [
    {
        name: 'groceries',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'milk',
                checked: false
            },
            {
                name: 'eggs',
                checked: false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'cvs',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'pills',
                checked: false
            },
            {
                name: 'cotton balls',
                checked: false
            },
            {
                name: 'razors',
                checked: false
            }
        ]
    }
];


app.controller('notepadController', function(){
    this.lists = shoppingLists;
    this.list = {};

    this.addList = function() {
        this.lists.push(this.list);
        this.list = {};
    };

});

app.controller('ItemController', function(){
    this.item = {};

    this.addItem = function(list){
        list.items.push(this.item);
        this.item = {};
    };

    this.removeItem = function(list, index) {
        list.items.splice(index, 1);
    };
});
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a new list in two places; once on controller initialization, and again in the `addList` function.

In both places, you need an `items` array to match the structure being used by the other list.  In both places where you create a new list, change your initialization code to `this.list={items:[]};` in order to ensure that there is an `items []` to push into.

Comment: That does add new items to new lists, but when I create a new list, its name doesn't appear at the top in the same way "groceries" and "cvs" appears.